# Throw sqlite insert error in node application without stopping node server

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a sqlite table that has a unique constraint on one of the columns. When I run a statement that attempts to write a duplicate, an error is given in the console, but the application terminates. Can I throw the error somewhere without terminating the server? this is the code I've been using:

```
db.run("INSERT INTO companies (company, location) VALUES (?,?)", [ input.name, input.location ], function(err){ 
        if(err) throw err;
    });
```

With the console logging:

```
node/db.js:6
        if(err) throw err;
                      ^
Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: companies.company
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could if you use something like [domains](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/domain.html) possibly. However, typically what is done is you pass the error to a callback (e.g. `if (err) return callback(err);`) that is passed in to the function containing your `db.run()`.